# What does "Editors" do in Oracle Forms ? How it works?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

How "Editors" section -that is under module- works? What does this thing do? I searched about it but didn't get it.[image]

Comment: My Forms is very rusty, but I seem to recall we could define editors (e.g. Notepad) to provide enhanced edit capability ,especially useful for free text fields.

Comment: There's a title **About Editors** invoked from `Help -> Online Help -> Index(Dizin)  -> Editor` in Forms Designer that describes **Editors** well.

Comment: It's just a small window that allows you to edit a text (as its name indicates).